# Use a different layouts/main.gsp based on environment in Grails

Tags: grails, build, gsp

I am trying to have two distinct layouts for my application. Most of the changes are CSS based, however some elements might also get moved around(such as moving a navbar from the top to the side). I decided the easiest would be is to have two main layouts, and pick one based on the environment that I compile for.

I am reading about the [grails event scripts and how to hoop up on there](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.4/guide/commandLine.html#events). Ideally I would like to have red_main.gsp and blue_main.gsp and copy one of them to main.gsp during build time. Examples online on this are very limited and I would appreciate some insight.

Thank you!

Comment: You can also use ${ENV}_main.gsp in your render layout code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did for anyone stuck in the same boat. This is my `scripts/_Events.gsp` file:

```
eventCompileStart = { msg -> 
   def envn = grails.util.Environment.current.name
   def mainName = "";
   if( envn.contains("_red" ) ) {
       mainName = "main_red.gsp"
   }
   else { 
       mainName = "main_blue.gsp"
   }

   ant.copy(file: "${basedir}/grails-app/views/layouts/${mainName}", 
           tofile: "${basedir}/grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp", 
           overwrite: true) 
}
```